# How to display month and year selection for credit card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 3.1 . Here is the code I have which asks user to enter credit card expiration month and year.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :expires_on, 'Expiration date' %>
    <br />
    <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: 'creditcard[month]', id: "card_month"} %>
    <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: 'creditcard[year]', id: "card_year"} %>
  </div>
```

Above code works. However the issue is that if there was a validation error then the selected expiration and month are reset.

I tried `f.select_month` but that is not supported.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :expires_on, 'Expiration date' %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :expires_on, :discard_day => true, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => (Date.today.year+10), :use_month_numbers => true %>
</p>
```

Comment: Is there a way to flip the order in which they appear? The year shows up first, and then the months

Comment: You can set the order with `:order`. For example `:order => [:month, :year]`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select